# Consider $F(x,y)=f(x+3y,2x-y)$...

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

If $f: \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where $F(x,y)=f(x+3y,2x-y)$ with $f$ is defferentiable and $\nabla f(0,0)=(4,-3)$ compute the derivate at the origin in the direction of unit vector $\vec{v}=(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$

---

---

Hi, I have some problems with this, it is possible that some concepts are flying on my mind but I don't know how I could solve the problem, help me? thanks

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you've tried, what theorem or technique you think might be applicable, etc. ? That'll help us gauge how best to write our answers.

Comment: I did this: $\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}(0,0)=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(2\sqrt{2}t,\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}t)-f(0,0)}{t}$ but I don't know how I can continue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(0,0)&=&\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)+2\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=4+2(-3)=-2\\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(0,0)&=&3\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=3(4)-(-3)=15,
\end{eqnarray}
we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial\vec{v}}(0,0)=\nabla F(0,0)\cdot\vec{v}=\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(0,0),\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(0,0)\right)\cdot\vec{v}=(-2,15)\cdot\left(\frac{\sqrt2}{2},\frac{\sqrt2}{2}\right)=\frac{13\sqrt2}{2}.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: MMmmm but... $ \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y)=\frac{\partial f(a(x,y),b(x,y))}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial f(a(x,y),b(x,y))}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a(x,y)}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f(a(x,y),b(x,y))}{\partial b}\frac{\partial b(x,y)}{\partial x}=$

$1\frac{\partial f(a(x,y),b(x,y))}{\partial a}+2\frac{\partial f(a(x,y),b(x,y))}{\partial b}$ no??

Comment: @Willyf Then substitute $x=0, y=0$, what do you get?

Answer (score 1):

$f'(c,u)=\nabla f(c) . u=(4,-3). (\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})= 4\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-3\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$
 ( "." is inner product symbole.)

Comment: oh, i didnot notice $F$. :(

Answer (score 0):

Directional derivative of $f$ at $c$ in the direction $u$ is given by $$f'(c,u)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(c+hu)-f(c)}{h}.$$